# Use of unresolved identifier 'questionList"

Tags: swift, var, identifier, undeclared-identifier

I know this error means that the compiler doesn't recognize the name, but I'm not sure how to fix it. How would I set the variable differently in order for it to function correctly? I assume it has to do something with questionsList being a var as opposed to a class? Or maybe it needs to be included somewhere else in the line?

```
var score = 0
for question in questionsList {
score += question.selectedAnswerIndex!**
```

(Full code below: I've deleted some  of the code in the middle in order to clean this up to post, but it shouldn't be an issue. I also starred where the issue is appearing)

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
var questionString: String?
var answers: [String]?
var selectedAnswerIndex: Int?
}

class QuestionController: UITableViewController {

let cellId = "cellId"
let headerId = "headerId"

var questionsList: [Question] = [Question(questionString: "What is your favorite type of food?", answers: ["Sandwiches", "Pizza", "Seafood", "Unagi"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "What do you do for a living?", answers: ["Paleontologist", "Actor", "Chef", "Waitress"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "Were you on a break?", answers: ["Yes", "No"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Question"

        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        tableView.register(AnswerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.register(QuestionHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerId)

        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.index(of: self) {
            let question = questionsList[index]
            if let count = question.answers?.count {
                return count
            }
        }
        return 0

....

class ResultsController: UIViewController {

    let resultsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Congratulations, you'd make a great Ross!"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("done")))

        navigationItem.title = "Results"

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        view.addSubview(resultsLabel)
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": resultsLabel]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": resultsLabel]))

        let names = ["Ross", "Joey", "Chandler", "Monica", "Rachel", "Phoebe"]

        **var score = 0
        for question in questionsList {
            score += question.selectedAnswerIndex!**
        }

        let result = names[score % names.count]
        resultsLabel.text = "Congratulations, you'd make a great \(result)!"
    }
```

Comment: `questionsList` is declared in `QuestionController`. It is not accessible in `ResultsController`. Any object is visible only in its own scope (the `{}` it's declared within).

Comment: @vadian right - so do I just copy/paste it again to declare in ResultsController? (not sure how to declare)

Comment: Make it a global, or pass it to ResultsController.

Comment: Please don't abuse the [xcode] tag and its related forms. Only use the [xcode] tag if your question directly concerns the Xcode IDE and only use its version tags ([xcode9] and [xcode9-beta]) if your question concerns a specific change related to that version of Xcode.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for letting me know! Did not know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the questions are hard-coded move them into the `Question` struct as class property

```
struct Question {
    let questionString: String
    let answers: [String]
    var selectedAnswerIndex: Int?

    static let questionsList : [Question] = [Question(questionString: "What is your favorite type of food?", answers: ["Sandwiches", "Pizza", "Seafood", "Unagi"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "What do you do for a living?", answers: ["Paleontologist", "Actor", "Chef", "Waitress"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "Were you on a break?", answers: ["Yes", "No"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil)]

}
```

and call it from everywhere

```
Question.questionsList
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it like this with `static` keyword

```
class QuestionController: UITableViewController {
 static  let questionsList: [Question] = [Question(questionString: "What is your favorite type of food?", answers: ["Sandwiches", "Pizza", "Seafood", "Unagi"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "What do you do for a living?", answers: ["Paleontologist", "Actor", "Chef", "Waitress"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil), Question(questionString: "Were you on a break?", answers: ["Yes", "No"], selectedAnswerIndex: nil)]
```

to access use

```
QuestionController.questionsList
```